# c# pass different variables to button onClick event

Tags: c#, winforms

I would need different variables on button_Click event. For each button I need different billDetail and rowAmount values. Actually every button is giving the last values of the var Size.
I think is a easy problem but I'm doing this as hobby...please help me!

```
private void CashCounter_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var posXbutton = 120;
    var posYbutton = 10;
    var gapXbutton = 105;
    var gapYbutton = 65;
    var posXlabel = 5;
    var posYlabel = 28;
    var gapYlabel = 65;

    using (var db = new GelatoProjectDBEntities())
    {
        #region working code
        var items = (from x in db.ProductsLists
                    select new { x.Id, x.Product, x.Category, x.Size, x.Price, x.Market, x.Image }
                    ).Where(x => x.Market == "Retail")
                    .ToArray();

        var categories = (from x in items
                          select x.Category)
                          .Distinct();

        foreach (var category in categories)
        {
            TabPage TabProduct = new TabPage(category);
            TabProduct.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            tabControl1.TabPages.Add(TabProduct);

            var products = (from i in items
                            where i.Category == category
                            select i.Product)
                            .Distinct()
                            .ToList();
            foreach (var product in products)
            {
                string labelName = "label" + product;
                var label = new Label();
                label.AutoSize = false;
                label.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(posXlabel, posYlabel);
                label.Name = labelName;
                label.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(110, 17);
                label.TabIndex = 0;
                label.Text = product;
                label.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
                posYlabel = posYlabel + gapYlabel;
                TabProduct.Controls.Add(label);

                var sizes = (from i in items
                            where i.Product == product
                            //select i.Size)
                            select new { i.Id, i.Product, i.Category, i.Size, i.Price, i.Market, i.Image })
                            .Distinct()
                            .ToList();

                foreach (var size in sizes)
                {
                    BillDetail = size.Size+" "+product;
                    BillTotal = "£   "+size.Price;
                    RowAmount = size.Price;
                    string buttonName = "button" + product;
                    var button = new Button();
                    button.Location = new Point(posXbutton, posYbutton);
                    button.Name = buttonName;
                    button.Size = new Size(100, 50);
                    button.Text = size.Size;
                    button.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
                    button.Click += new System.EventHandler(button_Click);
                    posXbutton = posXbutton + gapXbutton;
                    TabProduct.Controls.Add(button);
                }
                posXbutton = 120;
                posYbutton = posYbutton + gapYbutton;
            }
            posXbutton = 120;
            posYbutton = 10;
            gapXbutton = 105;
            gapYbutton = 65;
            posXlabel = 5;
            posYlabel = 28;
            gapYlabel = 65;
        }
    }
#endregion
}

private void button_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem NewBillProduct = new ListViewItem(BillDetail);
    NewBillProduct.SubItems.Add("£");
    NewBillProduct.SubItems.Add(RowAmount.ToString("F"));
    listViewBillDetail.Items.Add(NewBillProduct);

    BillTotalAmount = BillTotalAmount + double.Parse(RowAmount.ToString("F"));
    ItemsTotal = ItemsTotal + 1;
    textBoxTotal.Text = (BillTotalAmount.ToString("C", nfi)).ToString();
    textBoxItems.Text = (ItemsTotal).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Make your own custom `EventArgs`

Comment: Instead of manually create and locate buttons consider to use `DataGridView` which will do it for you based on the provided data

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Tag` property of `Button` to store related `Size` object there:

```
 button.Tag = size;
```

Then in click event handler you can retrieve this object:

```
private void button_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    var size = (Size)button.Tag;
    // use size.Size or size.Price        
    // etc
}
```

Note: You can store several objects in `Tag` if you'll put them into array or list.

Comment: Thank you so much Sergey, I'm trying but using size. it doesn't show me any size variables...

Comment: @Mirko probably you forgot to cast `Tag` to `Size` type

Comment: this is into the foreach statement:
button.Tag = size;

        private void button_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var button = (Button)sender;
            var size = (Size)button.Tag;

Comment: @Mirko that is an assignment. I'm talking about reading tag value in event handler

Comment: @Mirko will, I already wrote a sample above - see `button_Click` code

Comment: Sergey, I've copied that code and if I text size. doesn't it show every var into size?

Comment: @Mirko sorry, I cannot understand your last message. What does it mean `if I text size`? Text supposed to be a verb here? And what is `show every var into size`? Which vars you are talking about?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm explain you in wrong words...
I need different values from size object that I should get with the code size.price for example. If I put in my code size.price, it doesn't find any value price inside size. I will update my previous code hoping I will be understood.

Comment: @Mirko I rolled back your edits, because you have modified original question and replaced your code with code from answer

Comment: @Mirko I don't understand what is wrong with the code above - you store each `size` variable in each button, and then you retrieve each stored size from button when you click that button. What else do you need?

Comment: the code is good but when inside the void button I'm trying to get size variables, it doesn't give me anything...
should it give me for example the variable size.Price right?in case it doesn't give me this variable but the object size is full of variables...

Comment: @Mirko it should give you exactly same size object which you have assigned to button during creation `button.Tag = size`. If that size object don't have price value assigned, then you will not get price in the click event handler

Comment: the problem is that the object size is full and Price variable is in...when I try to get doing var priceproduct = size.Price I lose th size variables...
            var button = (Button)sender;
            var size = (object)button.Tag;
            var priceProduct = size.
after size. if I put Price the message if object doesn't contain a definition for price...

Comment: @Mirko there is no such code neither in my answer nor in my comments `var size = (object)button.Tag`